# Multiple monitors with MAC latop/PC: how to switch output?

Tags: multiple-monitors, kvm-switch

I have two monitors, a PC that uses both of them, and a MAC laptop.

The dilemma in my mind is how to keep the two monitor state in the PC active, while still being able to switch one monitor to the laptop's output.

Is this even possible? I figure as soon as output is switched, my PC will detect a monitor has been unplugged, and will switch to a one-monitor state.

The ideal would be to have a switch that switches from the PC two monitor output state to one where one monitor is being used by the MAC.

Comment: Depends on what monitor you are using, on my monitor I can plug in a DVI, HDMI and VGA cable and can switch between the input. The laptop never falls back to single screen mode if I switch the input (unless I pull the cable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a KVM switch.  You would plug one of the monitors into the switch and have the PC and the laptop both output to the switch.  Using a KVM switch is not like plugging and unplugging devices.

A proper KVM switch will maintain the sync and data signals to the PC and to the Mac so that both devices believe a monitor is present even though the monitor is only displaying output from one or the other.

The same goes for mouse and keyboard signals if you plug those devices into the switch; the computers connected to the switch never know that the real devices are not always present.